# Spring Boot with <dependencyManagement>

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, dependency-management

I'm creating a Spring Boot application this way :

[image]

I'm wondering how can I import `spring-webmvc` ?

Because in the POM of `spring-boot-dependencies` there is no `<dependency>spring-mvc</dependency>`

Obviously there is probably other jars that depends on `spring-mvc`, but no direct `spring-mvc` dependency in `spring-boot-dependencies` POM

Comment: Use the web starter.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t.

Instead:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Which depends on `spring-webmvc`.